# Is working as a software developer in a Stock company permissible?

Tags: sharia, investment

Assalamu Alaykum, recently I received an offer from a company that develops a software where users can buy stocks from different companies. After buying stock their stock will be saved to their pension account and they can only use their stock when they retire. Of course, in that app we develop, there will be some halal stocks alongside haram ones.So in this case is it permissible for me to work there? My role in that company, will be developing and maintaining and app for stock buyers.

Answer (score 1):

Wa Alaikkum wa salaam

I used to work in a software company around 20 years back and they were developing accounting software. But later on they turned to banking software development and I had to work in that. But after working for 1 or 2 years, I asked one Islamic scholar and he told it is safe not to work in banking software and I left the job. Since then I am working as a freelancer software developer. Alhamdulillah, I still appreciate that decision, as I worked on lot of interesting projects, including some very popular Quran projects. There Quran software are still available as freeware for people learning Quran in depth. Also I was able to meet lot of nice people through out the world.

So problem in working software company is you will be put on projects that you don't like and you will have to work on it as you are receiving salary. What your company does now may be ok for you but after you join the company they may decide to do something you don't like. This risk is there when working in any software company.

Comment: I don't think that "banking software" as such is haram. Say you have stocks in halal companies, don't you want some software to use for it?

Comment: I still don't know if it is haram or halaal but whatever decision I took, I think it is for good. I don't have any regrets. I got privilege to develop something for Allah's Quran. That I think is a great blessing..

Comment: @GyroGearloose btw, thank you for making my points cross 1000. Jazzakka Allahu Khair.

Comment: Hope you use it wisely. If you don't I'll turn into a jinn and will haunt your dreams ;-) .

Comment: لا قوة الا بالله